# How to save a v4l2 buffer image using OpenCV 4.2

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, rtsp, v4l2

I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with an equivalent board to the Auvidea B101 which is a HDMI to MIPI bridge. The board works correctly and I can save images using the code from my gist ( https://gist.github.com/danriches/80fadc21b5f1b0ca8ba725a8dd598710 ). However when I try to use OpenCV 4.2.0 (compiled locally and samples all work!) I get a segfault as detailed in the comments section of the gist. I can't for the life of me work out why though. If someone has a B101 or equivalent that uses the TC358743 chipset and has it working with OpenCV I'd be greatly appreciative if you have any advice or suggestions.

This all needs to work as fast as possible so apps calling apps is no good, I need to process the buffer and write it to a gstreamer pipe eventually. In fact if I could take the jpeg I get out the original code at line 832 and pass it to an instance of gst-rtsp-server then I'd be a happy man.

Any takers??

Dan

Comment: Could you clarify what you have done and are trying to do please? You have an unspecified, non-CSI camera attached to a Raspberry Pi CSI port using a Jetson adapter? You have taken some unspecified `v4l2` code and are trying to add in OpenCV support? Are you running this from the command line or from some system startup script? Do you have `DISPLAY` set and an X11 server?

Comment: I'm trying to get frames from a MIPI-CSI device (not a camera but HDMI) and this is done with v4l2 framework and mmal using 6by9's code which works. I'm trying to get each frame so I can either save them as a jpg or save the frames to a video file whilst streaming by piping them to gst-rtsp-server. I guess by Jetson adapter you're talking about an equivalent B101 board, if so then yes but it's my own design and does work correctly. This is being called by a startup service but also from the command line for testing. Thanks for taking a look and I really appreciate any help you can give.. Dan

Comment: For original code see here: https://github.com/6by9/v4l2_mmal